# Which vendors have a lot of cash?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So I just escaped from the Sierra Madre Vault with 37 gold bars. They are worth 9k each.

It will obviously take me a while to sell them all. Which vendors have the most caps? I know Gun Runners is one of them (they usually have 8k). Are there any other vendors with 5k+ caps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The wiki here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_bar) has a list of the vendors to sell them to that should be able to afford to give you the full value of the gold bars. Remember that they'll refill their caps every so often, but it'll involve a lot of resting.

As stated in the wiki page:

> - The hologram vendors in the Sierra Madre each have 2,500 units of pre-War money. Bear in mind that you will only be able to do this before leaving the Sierra Madre as you can't return.
> - [The Vendortron](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vendortron)   at the Gun Runners has around 8,000 caps.
> - The Quartermaster in the Brotherhood of Steel Bunker; [Knight Torres](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Torres) often has 8,000 caps.
> - [Daniel Contreras](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Daniel_Contreras) the NCR Supply Merchant in Camp McCarran also
>     usually has 8,000 caps and above.
> - [Arms merchant](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arms_merchant), A supply merchant at
>     the 188 Trading Post usually has around 8,000 caps or more.
> - [Alexander](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander), a Gun Runner merchant at the 188 Trading Post also has
>     8,000 caps or more.
> - [Blake](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Blake_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)) will sometimes spawn with 12,000 caps or
>     more.
> - [Old Lady Gibson](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Lady_Gibson) may have 8,000 or more caps later in the game.
> - [Sink Central Intelligence Unit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sink_Central_Intelligence_Unit) has a variable high amount, up to
>     24,000 caps.
> - [The Commissary terminals](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Commissary_terminal) in the Divide will have around
>     6,000 caps, and will replenish anytime their reserves drop below 200
>     caps after the player exits the menu.
> - [Calamity](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Calamity) in the Jacobstown lodge usually has around 4,000 caps or more later in the game.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: If you click the link to the wiki page, it lists the viable vendors with 5k+ caps, per her question. The information is right there, already nice and clean without my copy/pasting it all.

Comment: as a rule of thumb it's much more preferable to leave content in the answer to prevent link rot.

Comment: @oamlyya Fair enough.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the Old World Blues DLC then:

- Speak to the [Sink Central Intelligence Unit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sink_Central_Intelligence_Unit)

  - According to the wiki it can hold up to 14000 - 16000 caps, but I've seen it hold up to 20000 caps at one time.

If you have the Lonesome Road DLC then:

- [Commissaries](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Commissary_terminal) will hold up to 6000 caps, but once they drop below 200 caps their stock of caps INSTANTLY refreshes.  So this could be an easy to well to sell the gold bars quickly (just enter, exit trading menu, reenter), but you'll end up losing quite a bit of money.

If no DLC:

- Once you have reached a high enough level Gun Runners can carry up to 8000 caps, although the time for them to replenish this stock can take a while.